# Prison break: a minimisation problem

Tags: graph-theory, optimization, algorithms

> Consider a prison with $n$ prisoners. Each cell contains a phone which
>   can be used to call any other cell. Each prisoner has a different
>   piece of information which, when put together, will allow them to make
>   a successful escape. To avoid suspicion, they wish to minimise the number of calls that need to
>   be made such that all of them know the information.
>
> What is the mimimum?

For notational purposes let the set of individuals be $\{p_1,\;\cdots , \;p_n\}$, and let $p_i\to p_j$ indicate a phone call from $p_i$ to $p_j$. It is understood that in any such phone call, $p_i$ and $p_j$ exchange all the information they have.

---

After considering small cases, it would appear the minimum is $2n-4$ when $n\geq 4$. One can easily show that this is sufficient. For instance, consider the following algorithm:

- $n=2m:$ Let $p_{2i-1}\to p_{2i}$ for $i=1,\,2,\,\cdots ,\,m\;\;(m$ calls$)$. Let $p_{2m}\to p_{2i}$ for $i=m-1,\,\cdots ,\,2,\,1\;\;(m-1$ calls $)$. At this point $p_{2m}$ and $p_2$ have all the information. Let $p_1\to p_4$, who both have all the information now. We are left with $\{p_3,\;p_5,\;p_6,\cdots p_{2m-1}\}$, $\text{i.e.}\;2m-4$ individuals without all the information. Let $p_1\to p_i$ for all $p_i$ in this set and every prisoner can now escape after exactly $4m-4\;\text{i.e.}\;2n-4$ calls.
- $n=2m+1:$ Consider the previous case, but let $p_{2m+1}\to p_1$ before the chain of calls and $p_{2m+1}\to 1$ again at the end of the chain. The information is passed in $4m-2\;\text{i.e.}\;2n-4$ calls.

---

The difficult part is showing that $2n-4$ is in fact necessary, and I have had no luck with it. I feel a knowledge of graph theory might help. The problem comes from a series of exercises which were set as part of a course in elementary number theory. Hints or ideas would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What about for $n=2,3$? You have $0$ and $2$ calls respectively in those cases. You would need $1$ when $n=2$ and $3$ when $n=3$...

Comment: @doppz Apologies, I forgot to type in $n\geq 4$. The lower cases are trivial of course.

Comment: I'm reminded of a "gossip problem". Are you familiar with semigroups? I think they might be helpful here.

Comment: @Shaun I am not, but I shall look them up.

Comment: @Lachryma Papaveris: I mention semigroups because, if I recall correctly, you can view the act of exchanging information in this case as the binary operation of a semigroup; I could be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

This is also known as the "Gossip Problem" and is a classic problem. Incidentally it appeared as the last question on an example sheet for the "Numbers and Sets" course at Cambridge this year.

**Hint:**  Use induction for $n \geq 4$, assume on the contrary that there is an algorithm with $ \leq 2n-5$ calls, then use the induction hypothesis to prove the following lemma: "No prisoner hears his own information from some other prisoner"

(Strictly speaking $2n-4$ is the minimum only for $n \geq 4$; you have to consider the small cases seperately.)

Knowledge of graph theory will definitely be a good boost to helping you solve the problem, but since not much graph theory is needed for the proof, it is entirely possible (but harder) to come up with a proof without using any graph theory.

Comment: Thanks for the hint. And yes, that is precisely where I have taken the problem from - thought I should spice it up with prisoners rather than dons.

Comment: This question is a Cambridge tradition -- it was on the Cambridge Numbers & Sets sheets 12 years ago when I was a first-year undergrad. (I didn't solve it :-) )